# Android kills my app after some time in background

Tags: java, android, background

I have an app that sends TCP messages. I need the messages to be sent as long as the app is alive. So, I granted access to battery optimization and added all the required wake_locks and everything seems to work fine even when screen is off. 
The problem is that I noticed that every time that I leave my phone with the app in the background, when I come back after few hours(or less)  no messages are being sent, and when I enter my app it loads as new instance and not like an app coming from background. What can I do to have my app not being killed by Android?  [image]

I guess that this is what happens

Comment: If you want background actions, you need to use a Service.

Comment: Service that does what? Open my activity again? @TheWanderer

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a foreground [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services); a service started via `startForeground()`.

The service does not "re-open" your activity; it is a component of your application that may be long-lived. You might prefer to think of it as an activity without any views.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as the others mention you have to use Service for background execution.

Additionally, also, keep in mind of the [Background Execution Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background) for Oreo and above.

You can also look at [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling) for managing asynchronous tasks efficiently.

Answer (score -1):

1. Create a 1px*1px transparent view on the desktop, such as toast.(the Android os will level up your priority as a foreground process)
2. Suggest your user to add your app in the white list.(in some rom)
3. Always put your app`s notification in the notification bar.(also need a service)
4. create a guard process, when your app die, send a broadcast to guard and let guard restart your app. when guard die, send a broadcast to app and let app restart your guard.

**Be careful of battery consumption and don`t trouble your users too much**